# Как лучше считать время между 0 и 1 в миллисекундах

Tags: c++, arduino

Прикрутил к ардуино датчик освещения. Когда свет горит - на дисплее 0, когда света нет - 1. Как вычислить и вывести время в миллисекундах между выключенным и включены светом?

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> //дисплей

int ledPin = 13; //светодиод на 13 порту
int inPin = 2;   // на 2 входе
int val = 0;     // переменная для хранения значения


LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

void setup()
{ 
    lcd.begin(16, 2); // устанавливаем количество столбцов и строк на ЖК-дисплее:
    //lcd.print("hello, world!");  // Выводим сообщение на ЖК-дисплей.
    Serial.begin(9600); //скорость передачи данных
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    val = digitalRead(inPin); //считывет значение с 2го
    if (val == 0)
    {
        lcd.print (val);; //устанавливает значение на светодиод равное значению входа 5 вольт
        delay(1);
        lcd.clear();
    }
    lcd.print(val);
    delay(100);
    lcd.clear();
}
```

Comment: подвесить прерывание на ногу: по фронту запомнить время, а по спаду — получить длительность...

Comment: *точнее наоборот: по спаду — запомнить время включения, а по фронту вычислить длительность...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Приветствую! Для этого подойдет millis() ?

Comment: для плучения времени — да.

Comment: Правильно понимаю, необходимо создать переменную хранящее время например int timeMy = 0;

и в функции

 if(val== 0) {
 timeMy = millis();
}

а потом вывести значение 

 timeMy?

Comment: Какой бесполезный у вас if, это эффект помыргивания реализован? =)

Comment: @vp_arth Привет. Как сделать чтобы это было не бесполезным? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дела с Ардуинами не имел, вероятно пишу дичь)

```
int last_state = 0;
int val = 0;

uint32_t switch_time;
uint32_t duration_0;
uint32_t duration_1;

void loop() {
  val = digitalRead(inPin);
  if (last_state != val) { // Состояние изменилось, делаем замеры
    uint32_t now_time = millis();
    if (val == 0) {
      duration_0 = 0;
      duration_1 = now_time - switch_time;
      // lcd.print(duration_1);
    } else {
      duration_0 = now_time - switch_time;
      duration_1 = 0;
      lcd.print(duration_0);
    }
    switch_time = millis();
  }
  last_state = val;
  // ...
}
```

<sub>Скорее всего, лучше всё это вынести в обработчик прерывания а в основном цикле просто печатать волатильную переменную.</sub>

Comment: /var/folders/zn/jrv1sf4n6fn8qdfbcxxz0w800000gp/T/arduino_modified_sketch_584825/HelloWorld.ino: In function 'void loop()':
HelloWorld:21:8: error: 'lcd' was not declared in this scope
        lcd.print  (durationI);
        ^~~
exit status 1
'lcd' was not declared in this scope

Спасибо! Но компилятор выдает такую ошибку.

Comment: У вас же в коде оно было объявлено, зачем убрали?

Comment: Я только написал код «засекания времени», всё остальное, настройку пинов и т.п. стоило оставить на месте)

Comment: Точно! Накосячил! Подправил, но теперь другая ошибка 
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Mac OS X), Плата:"Arduino Uno"

/var/folders/zn/jrv1sf4n6fn8qdfbcxxz0w800000gp/T//cczABh8l.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
/private/var/folders/zn/jrv1sf4n6fn8qdfbcxxz0w800000gp/T/AppTranslocation/B7D9B883-6EDD-49BA-BED7-52BDE4D700CF/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/main.cpp:43: undefined reference to `setup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Ошибка компиляции для платы Arduino Uno.

Comment: верните setup =)

Comment: Туплю как ардуино)

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как посчитать наоборот, сколько датчик находится в миллисекундах на свету до выключения а не в темноте до включения?

Comment: Там в коде как раз 2 переменные, напечатайте другую в соседней ветке)

Comment: duration_0 - сколько последнее время был 0, duration_1 - про единицу)

Comment: Мозгов не хватает что это понять) Попробовал условия поменять местами, что-то не то(

Comment: Перенёс print в ответе, посмотрите)